# Mongodb, trying to set dbpath to ancient database directory

Tags: database, mongodb

I had to reinstall mongodb on Ubuntu 18.04.
By default the dbpath is `/var/lib/mongodb` (an empty directory populated with files like mongodb.lock when mongo session starts).
I changed the configuration in the concerned file `/etc/mongod.conf` for `dbPath: /home/.../mongodatabases` *Notice the 3 dots just mention the path is longer. I shorted it in this question for convinience.* 
`/home/.../mongodatabases` is populated with files and databases I used before having to reinstall mongo. So `mongod` fails to run.

The `mongodb.log` file tells:

```
{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},
"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},
"storage":{"dbPath":"/home/.../mongodatabases","journal":{"enabled":true}},
"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-21T12:00:37.043+01:00"},
"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten",
"msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating",
"attr":{"error":"Location28596: Unable to determine status of lock file in the data directory /home/.../mongodatabases: 
 boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: \"/home/.../mongodatabases/mongod.lock\""}}
```

while `sudo ls -l` indicates it owns it `rwxrwx--- 1 mongodb mongodb        0 mars  20 18:41 mongod.lock`. I doubt this is the real reason.

I tried with `sudo mongodb --repair` and rebooting the machine, it stills fails:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-03-21 12:13:16 CET; 2min 40s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2301 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 2301 (code=exited, status=100)

mars 21 12:13:15 avywam systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
mars 21 12:13:16 avywam systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
mars 21 12:13:16 avywam systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So, how to get back my old data in `/home/.../mongodatabases` ?

```
(base) avy@machine:~/.../mongodatabases# ls -l
total 281948
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    20480 mars   9 22:57 collection-0-1466723540485185104.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    24576 sept.  6  2022 collection-0-3623937307298719216.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    86016 déc.   9 00:06 collection-0--4427681232844188294.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb 62230528 déc.  15 16:49 collection-0--559532783025448254.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb 76791808 déc.  15 16:49 collection-0-8406113464061954964.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb   102400 mars   9 22:58 collection-2-1466723540485185104.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb 94830592 déc.   8 00:39 collection-2-1504170641214360967.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb 48427008 déc.  15 16:49 collection-2--8782359578404508998.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    12288 déc.  15 16:49 collection-4-1466723540485185104.wt
drw-rwx--- 2 avy     mongodb    12288 mars   9 22:59 diagnostic.data
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    20480 mars   9 22:57 index-1-1466723540485185104.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    24576 sept.  6  2022 index-1-3623937307298719216.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    45056 déc.   9 00:06 index-1--4427681232844188294.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb  1638400 déc.  15 16:49 index-1--559532783025448254.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb  1228800 déc.  15 16:49 index-1-8406113464061954964.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    36864 mars   9 22:58 index-3-1466723540485185104.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb   856064 déc.   8 00:39 index-3-1504170641214360967.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb  2048000 déc.  15 16:49 index-3--8782359578404508998.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    12288 déc.  15 16:49 index-5-1466723540485185104.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    12288 mars   9 22:59 index-6-1466723540485185104.wt
drw-rwx--- 2 avy     mongodb     4096 mars   9 22:57 journal
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    36864 mars   9 22:57 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rwxrwx--- 1 mongodb mongodb        0 mars  20 18:41 mongod.lock
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb    36864 mars   9 22:59 sizeStorer.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb      114 juin  20  2022 storage.bson
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb       50 juin  20  2022 WiredTiger
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb     4096 mars   9 22:57 WiredTigerHS.wt
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb       21 août   8  2022 WiredTiger.lock
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb     1465 mars   9 22:59 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw-rwx--- 1 avy     mongodb   118784 mars   9 22:59 WiredTiger.wt
```

Mongo version: 5.0.10

Comment: Do you try to start mongod more than once?

Comment: Is the `dbPath` really `/home/.../mongodatabases` (with **three** dots)? This would be an invalid path. Did you grant write permissions to entire `dbPath`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I reconsidered the question. The 3 dots are for convenience shorting of the path. All the dbPath (`/home/.../mongodatabases`) is allowed to mongo.

Comment: What about `ls -ld /home/.../mongodatabases`? When you start mongod service, then it should run as user `mongod` (or `mongodb` as it looks in your case). Thus all files should be owned by this user, not your personal user. Most likely you started `mongod` directly instead of the service. Anyway, I don't think it is a smart choice to put MongoDB data into your home folder. Should be better a dedicated path, e.g. `/var/lib/mongodb/`

Comment: Is selinux active on that machine?

Comment: @Joe I don't think this is even installed because after checking what is selinux the command `sudo getenforce` would return something but it returns the command is unfound. So I conclude I don't have selinux.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I consider this is smart enough when the MongoDB documentation explain it is allowed to change the `--dpath` argument in a [process](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) or service. My `/home` folder is the right choice for now, `/var/lib/mongodb` is too small for the usage I want.

Comment: Verify the file permissions with `sudo -u mongodb ls -ld "/home/.../mongodatabases"`